# time-series in a few attributes

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, feature-extraction

Given a time-series of lab test data which could contain one or more values, is there any way to capture the dynamics of the test data using a few attributes?

For example, if I have a list of values taken in time [0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7], can I use some fixed number of attributes to basically represent the changes in the time-series data?

Right now, I am only using mean, but it's certainly not enough to capture, such as increase or decrease.  Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're only interested in local averages and local differences, consider a Haar wavelet transform. However, without knowing your goal and what you mean by "capture the dynamics", it's hard to say what transformation best suits your purpose.

Comment: by dynamics, I mean for example the value keeps dropping, increasing, or wiggling.  Say the lab test if some medical test associated with a disease, and a high value indicates a bad condition of a patient with such disease.  Then if I can summarize the series of data into a few attributes and preserve the trend, then I can still get to know the condition of the patient by looking at the new features.

Comment: So, basically moments of the data, such as derivatives?

Comment: @sunside yes, that is one thing I need. I basically have no idea how to summarize the list into what attributes